# how can I find the layout parameters of the toast widget?

Tags: android, layout, parameters, toast

I like the layout of the `toast` widget very much, that means rounded corners, transparency, light grey border. Is there any way to see the layout parameters of such android standard widgets like the `toast`?

I would like do define a `TextView` with the same layout parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The layout can be found under
{SDKBASEDIR}/platforms/{RELEASE}/res/layout/transient_notification.xml

e.g. for 2.1:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/toast_frame">
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Small"
    android:textColor="@color/bright_foreground_dark"
    android:shadowColor="#BB000000"
    android:shadowRadius="2.75"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

The drawable toast_frame.9.png  can be found under {SDKBASEDIR}/platforms/{RELEASE}/res/drawable{-RESOLUTION}