# Supporting multiple screen sizes, some things look too small

Tags: android, android-layout

I am almost done my app, but when I did a test run on an `xlarge` screen, something odd happened. All the `EditText` fields, the text in all the buttons, and even the Toasts all appear much smaller relative to the size of the screen. It's almost as if they are the size they would be on a `normal` screen, but for some reason the app didn't scale them up to a larger size to fit the screen. My `EditText` fields are larger because they are using weights to specify a height, but the text you type in them is miniscule on the larger screens.

I was surprised that even the Toasts didn't scale up, aren't they an internal thing to the Android system?

I searched around, and found that I should include this in my manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I have it above my `application` tag and below my `users-sdk` tag, but still not luck.

Any idea about what's going on?

EDIT: I use `dp` units for everything. Toasts I create programatically though, the usual way. They look great on `normal` screens.

Comment: For textsize you could use sp instead of px or refer the sizes to a dimensions.xml that you should have one in each res folder size

Comment: which size units are you using in your layouts?

Comment: @nininho Ya that's what I am doing now, but what about the others. Like the Toasts. I'm sure other people use Toasts on larger screens.

Comment: @devmiles.com I am using `dp` for everything.

Comment: try using sp units for text size. if your any of your text or edit views are made to wrap_content they could just wrap small text and stay small.

Comment: @devmiles.com But what about the Toasts?

Answer (score 0):

Check your custom or overridden styles if you have any, they may be affecting your Toast size. Otherwise may create your own Toast subclass:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView

Here you can find the default Toast layout, as you can see it uses @style/TextAppearance.Small which is a built-in user customizable style:

[how can I find the layout parameters of the toast widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619670/how-can-i-find-the-layout-parameters-of-the-toast-widget)

Comment: have you had a chance to look at this?